# Glyph substitution: alternate capital Q in URW-Garamond? (LaTeX, Mac OS X)

Tags: fonts, characters, substitution

I am using URW Garamond in LaTeX running on Mac OS X. The capital Q has a very long swash (extending beyond the next two glyphs!), which makes it unusable for me (I have too many capital Q's in my writing, e.g. from Chinese pinyin, W.V.O. Quine, among others). I would like to use an alternate capital Q, with a normal swash, which I assume may exist in the font. I have looked in vain for a package or explanation how to make this switch. I would appreciate any suggestions on how to fix this.

PS. I am asking because I am considering using URW Garamond for a book soon to be published by an academic press, assuming I can fix this. If not, I will use the `fourier` package. For a number of reasons I cannot consider alternatives such as XeTeX. I am somewhat hesitant to try to install Adobe Garamond Premier Pro, but I might consider it if that is the only solution.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you. Apart from that, thanks for the well-posed question!

Comment: Is buying an OpenType Garamond an option? I don't think the Postscript font has any alternate glyphs but you can open it in in Fontforge and have a look. http://www.myfonts.com/person/Claude_Garamond/ is a list of Garamonds and there is a free-as-in-freedom one on https://github.com/georgd/EB-Garamond/downloads but this all means that you'd have to use LuaLaTeX (which is easier than switching to XeLaTeX from my experience).

Comment: Speaking of Fontforge, you can even try to change the Q you don't like. Small changes like this can turn out easier than you might think. I don't know whether this is legal though.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 6):

If using `fontspec` you can switch off the contextual alternates:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newopentypefeature{Contextuals}{NoAlternate}{-calt}
\defaultfontfeatures{Kerning=Uppercase,Mapping=tex-text,}
\setmainfont{Garamond Premier Pro}


\begin{document}
Quad Qed

\addfontfeatures{Contextuals=NoAlternate}
Quad Qed
\end{document}
```

[image: q-swash]

(Sorry I miss that you don’T want XeTeX, but I don’t delet this answer since it may help other searching for this question …)

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand the problem. With this example - which uses `ugmr8a.pfb` from `fonts/urw/garamond/` on CTAN I don't see any long swashes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\fontfamily{ugm}\selectfont
Que Qa
\end{document}
```

[image]