# Alternate Q in Garamond Premier Pro with XeLaTeX

Tags: fonts, xetex, typography

My question is closely related to [Glyph substitution: alternate capital Q in URW-Garamond? (LaTeX, Mac OS X)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57064/glyph-substitution-alternate-capital-q-in-urw-garamond-latex-mac-os-x) but I am using XeLateX. It looks like there is a hidden mechanism that I do not understand. I had a look at all the glyphs of the font using dp4FontViewer 2.0 and I could not find the Q with the very long swash. Instead, the two Qs shown on the right side of the image below are accessible. Q with code 0051 is used when it is isolated in the main text. It'd be nice if it could replace the one with the long swash which takes place in words with more than a single letter (a single Q then).

[image]

Comment: I think it is a [ligature](http://nitens.org/taraborelli/latex#ligatures). So you need some characters after Q to trigger that.

Comment: and do you know a way to not trigger that?

Comment: I've asked in the chat so probably one of our wizards would step in.

Comment: Thank you. And also, I can see the other ligatures of the font in the table of glyphs but not this one, which looks strange to me.

Comment: It's probably not a ligature but a context-dependent alternate glyph. Search for "CharacterVariant" in the `fontspec` documentation. You can also try if `Q\/ue` helps but that's more of an experiment, not a solution.

Comment: could it be possible to force this `Q\/` at the beginning of the document by, somehow, globally redefining `Q` as `Q\/`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question (XeLaTeX) has been accidentally answered by *Tobi* at [Glyph substitution: alternate capital Q in URW-Garamond? (LaTeX, Mac OS X)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57064/glyph-substitution-alternate-capital-q-in-urw-garamond-latex-mac-os-x).

You can use `fontspec` to switch off the contextual alternates (code by *Tobi*):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newopentypefeature{Contextuals}{NoAlternate}{-calt}
\defaultfontfeatures{Kerning=Uppercase,Mapping=tex-text,}
\setmainfont{Garamond Premier Pro}


\begin{document}
Quad Qed

\addfontfeatures{Contextuals=NoAlternate}
Quad Qed
\end{document}
```

[image: q-swash]